# Real-time form field select notification to firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-applications, firefox-addon

I am trying to write a firefox addon where I would like to know which of the form fields such as input field, checkbox and so on were selected.

For instance: On facebook.com, you will notice that there are 2 form fields: 1. Sign up and 2.Login. I would like my addon to recognize that the user is currently entering his user name when he has selected the "user name" input field and has selected password when he is entering the password.

I don't have a clue where to begin since this has to work for all web applications and I don't have the source. Any suggestions would really help.

Comment: they are all just inputs with standart names such as (User,UserName,NickName,Name,ID as ID Field) and (Password,Pass... etc. as Password field) so what you need to do is just focus them and test their values with previous cookies..